# how to make a association by using lucene/solr import record from database and doc file at same time

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-cell

i store binary documents information (file meta) in database, and store binary documents in filesystem. using file name associate with file information in database.

now i want to import all those data (file meta and full-text content in binary documents ) into lucene solr.

lucene/solr provide "Import records from a database using the Data Import Handler (DIH)." and "Index binary documents such as Word and PDF with Solr Cell (ExtractingRequestHandler). " to import those data separately.

How can i make a association between binary document and file meta with solr/lucene after importing

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567536/604511) a related question.

I implemented something like that by means of a client program that queries the DB, fetches rows corresponding to updated documents and then uploading the file as well as supplied metadata.